# Android library using their own resources

Tags: android, android-resources, android-library, r.java-file

I created an android library with resources. How i can use them? When I try using them I get a null pointer exception.

I checked R.java from the library and it is empty! I have one layout that I need to use in SimpleAdapter.

Thanks.

```
SimpleAdapter directoryEntriesAdapter = new SimpleAdapter(getContext(), 
    this.directoryEntries, 
    R.layout.directoryentries, 
    new String[] { "graph" }, 
    new int[] { R.id.directoryentries_textview });
```

Answer (score 1):

Its unclear how you created the library so I will attempt to answer the most likely ways.

**Option 1:**

If you have used the library as a "Android Library Project" in Eclipse/etc then you need to ensure the following:

- Under project properties - Android tab, there is a link between the app and the library project
- The R file that is imported is from the library project and not the app project.  If you need to use both then you will need to use the format `com.library.R.id.directoryentries_textview` in place of your current code

**Option 2:**

If you "compiled" the library in a jar file then the resources will not be included and therefore cannot be used.

**Option 3:**

If you compiled your library into an Gradle Android Resource (.aar) or Maven APKLIB (.apklib) file then the fixes are the same as option 1.  Verify and potentially modify the import.

Please note, currently the easiest and fastest way to do libraries in Android is Option 1.  At this time the Maven APKLIB does work but its a lot of learning for most people and the Gradle AAR file is somewhere between incomplete and broken depending on your perspective.

Comment: I use IntelliJ IDEA and created two projects (android application and android library).

On android application i add my android library in dependencies and set as library!

Comment: In that case, I'm sorry I can't help.  My experience with IntelliJ is somewhere close to non-existant

Comment: When you say: "there is a link between the app and the library project"  you mean circular reference?

Comment: I don't know what it is in IntelliJ but in Eclipse you have to goto the "Android" section of the Project properties and link the 2 projects together.  Sometimes (prob an eclipse bug) its also useful to add the lib project as a Build path dependancy (see "Java Build Path" then "Projects" tab